# Google Drive API Authentication in Backend in java

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I am using google drive api for desktop application to insert a file .To authenticate google drive i am using url that it generates and get Authentication code and paste it back in front end.

Plz suggest some other way such a way that it authenticates in the backend and uploads a file automatically.

Comment: what does the Google drive api documentation say?

Comment: i don have idea about Google drive api documentation.If there is any way with that please help me.

Comment: i have to insert a file into google drive with authentication being in the backend.Plz help me in achieving this

Answer (score 1):

You can cut out the copy-paste work for the user by implementing a webserver in Java that listens to a port on the localhost, something like `http://localhost:8181`. You would then use that URL as the redirect_uri parameter when requesting the refresh token. If your application also automatically opens the refresh token request page for the user then the authorization workflow should be relatively simple and straightforward for the user.

If you really want zero user interaction, you'll need to [use Service Accounts](https://developers.google.com/drive/service-accounts) and [have the service account delegated domain-wide authority to user's Google Drives](https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation):

Comment: Thank you for suggesting me to Use Service Accounts.

Comment: After creating a service account and Instantiating a Drive service object how do we insert a file on the google drive ???? Plz help in this regards..

Comment: i have used google service accounts and inserted a file using Java in eclipse,In eclipse it shows the File id (Created file).unable to find the doc in google drive. what would be the problem ?